# NSDateFormatter Can't format date

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I have tried and tried and researched and tried again but I cannot format this

The date is: 
    "2013-08-08T11:10:09-07:00"

I've tried using "yyyy'-'MM'-'DD'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ" and a host of different permutations of this but to no avail. I think perhaps the server is sending the incorrect format of the timezone.

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy'-'MM'-'DD'T'HH':'mm':'ssZ"];

return [dateFormatter dateFromString:[dictionary objectForKey:key]];
```

Any clues?

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://b2cloud.com.au/how-to-guides/nsdateformatter-format-strings Consult this, clue MM is wrong, DD is wrong.

Comment: Apologies, I have edited the post accordingly

Comment: Also, you do not need the ' ' marks

Comment: Try - "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZ"

Comment: I have adjusted it to @"yyyy-M-ddTHH:mm:ssZ" and still no luck :/

Comment: I tried your solution Jeff and am still getting a nil date

Comment: I can't answer my own question for 8 hours but my research has made me realise that the source data is incorrect. The timezone should not have a colon in it and should be -0700 instead of -07:00

Comment: The data you used in your example `2013-08-08T11:10:09-07:00` requires this format string to parse: `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ`. You need 5 `Z` characters for the non-localized ISO GMT offset that your source date is using.

Comment: awesome that worked! create the answer and I will mark it as correct. thanks!

Comment: @Jeff Also, if your dates are coming from the server or something, escaping the time/date separators is not a bad idea because there is discussion of turning those into locale-replacing variables like letters currently, and I believe that the apple stuff may even do that in some places. So, unescaped, those `:` and `-` could suddenly change behavior in the future.

Comment: Thanks Jason, good point! Will bear that in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the non-localized ISO offset that you're using—e.g., `-07:00`—you need to use 5 `Z` characters in your format. So, for the source data given, the correct format string would be:

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ
```

While the currently used technical standard doesn't require date and time separators to be escaped, as Jeff mentions in the comments, it's probably not a bad idea to do so, especially if your source date is coming from a server or something. There are discussions on making those replacements, like the letters, that would change for locale-specific date and time separators. It also doesn't hurt to escape them from a technical perspective, it's just harder to read:

```
yyyy'-'MM'-'dd'T'HH':'mm':'ssZZZZZ
```

For more information, the current date formatter is based on the Unicode Technical Spec #35. The date and time pattern specifications for #35 can be found at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-25.html#Date_Format_Patterns